# Login keychain disappears on login

Tags: keychain

Running 10.8.2 on MacBook Pro, sometime after upgrading to Mountain Lion 10.8.1 I started getting the message box that passwords, etc. could not be saved to keychain.  I did the usual (repair permissions, repair keychain).  It would make a new login keychain which is usually fine until I reboot my system (but not always) and then the login keychain disappears again.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try running repair permissions from the recovery partition so the keychain isn't in use and can properly be repaired.